# Why can't I add SwipeToRefresh to android studio?

Tags: javascript, android-studio

Whenever I attempt to add the code:

`<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout></android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>`

to my activity_main.xml file, android studio does not seem to have this layout installed. All the videos and examples I have seen seem to have android studio already familiar with the swipe refresh feature but mine does not. Whenever I go to my MainActivity.java to try and do any code involving any kind of swipe to refresh, I am given an error. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hi Mahcksi, you should revise your question to be more specific, post some code showing what you've tried, and explain which part you don't understand. Then you may get better responses.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency `implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"`
 and use `<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout></androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>` tag.